# Be careful to do/ about doing/ doing

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

This dialogue is from a TV series:

> A: So sorry I am late.
>
> B: Of course it happens... just would ***be careful being late*** to
>   appointments with CA's office...

---

> a- ... be ***careful about being*** late to appointments with CA's
>   office...
>
> b- ...be ***careful to be*** late to appointments with CA's office...
>
> c- ... be ***careful when you are*** late to appointments with CA's>
>   office...

Does the original phrase mean a or b or c or something else?

Comment: It sounds like it's highly elided: _[You] just would [need to] be careful [about.] being late to appointments._

Comment: @J.R. Thank you. Is it okay to omit "about" in this phrase: "need to be careful being late to..."

Comment: You need to be careful using television shows to provide model speech patterns.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this particular example is that any way you phrase it sounds wrong:
"being late to appointments" is bad. It's something to be avoided.  So is being stung by bees. Consider:

"just be careful to be stung by bees"
"just be careful when you are being stung by bees"

No.

Rather, the emphasis ought to be on avoiding the situation entirely.

> I would just be careful to *never* be late to appointments with CA's office.
>
> I would just be careful, and make sure to be on time to appointments with CA's office.